# Converting wxString to std::string for OpenCv

Tags: c++, opencv, wxwidgets

Anybody knows why my application crash everytime the code was parsing this line:

```
deskew(filename); //filename string
```

My declaration is like this:

```
void deskew(std::string fname);
```

And then I also used this code to convert my wxString to string:

```
string fname = string(path.mb_str());
```

I just read it from the tutorial but it isn't working.
And by the way, I'm using wxWidgets for my c++.

here is the body of deskew:

```
void DImage::deskew(string filename, unsigned int angle)
{

if (filename == "")
    return;
Mat img = imread(filename, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);

vector<Point> points;
Mat_<uchar>::iterator it = img.begin<uchar>();
Mat_<uchar>::iterator end = img.end<uchar>();
for (; it != end; ++it)
  if (*it)
    points.push_back(it.pos());

RotatedRect box = minAreaRect(Mat(points));

Mat rot_mat = getRotationMatrix2D(box.center, angle, 1);

Mat rotated;
warpAffine(img, rotated, rot_mat, img.size(), INTER_CUBIC);

Size box_size = box.size;
if (box.angle < -45.)
  swap(box_size.width, box_size.height);
Mat cropped;
  getRectSubPix(rotated, box_size, box.center, cropped);

//imshow("Original", img);
//imshow("Output", rotated);
//imshow("Cropped", cropped);

imwrite("icons/DESKEW.png", cropped);
waitKey(0);
}
```

Here it is, I've just paste it all so all of you can see.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, what you're doing should work (though I think you mean `std::string fname`).  Could be the error is elsewhere - we might need more context: how is `filename` declared/generated?  what's the body of `deskew` look like?

Comment: Are you using the debugger to see where it is 'crashing'?  Is it in one of the lines within the deskew method?

Comment: nope, it's not debugger error. The application is running, but when I enter an event that uses deskew function, that's where crashing happen.
Im using windows.

Comment: Where in the function is the crash happening?  How do you know if it is the string and not the OpenCV code?  It could be a problem in the way that the function call is being set up.

Comment: Cause i try to remove the functions `imread(filename, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);`, then the crashing is gone.
I've been thinking that maybe there's something wrong in the conversion.

Comment: Try stubbing the function like this: https://gist.github.com/1981051  What happens/what is the output?

Comment: Do you understand how to use the debugger to step through your code?  Then you can see where the crash occurs.

Comment: Yes i know, but i don't know how to use the command prompt in wxwidgets. I just can't make them appear.

Comment: You seem to be confused about using the debugger to step through your code.  This is your real problem.  Once you know how to do that, you will likely easily find the problem.

Comment: Learning the debugger will help.  In the mean time, you can get cout/printf output from a wx app in windows by either a) launching the app from the command prompt or b) reopen stdout/stderr to a console - example: https://gist.github.com/1981581

Answer (score 4):

Use `wxString::ToStdString()`, i.e.

```
string fname = path.ToStdString();
```

Edit: Also, you don't use `std::` consistently; if you are `using namespace std;` then you don't need it at all; otherwise `std::` needs to prefix `string` and other STL types/functions wherever they occur.

Comment: But sir, im only using wxwidgets 2.8.
That feature is from 2.9 right?

Comment: @kcirearraveug That I don't know, although the [changes page](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/2.9.3/overview_changes_since28.html]) doesn't say anything like this.  But if `ToStdString` isn't available then try `string(path.ToAscii())`.

Comment: It's a 2.9 thing.  `mb_str` should work, I think there's another problem.

Comment: @mattphillips Yes sir, Ive been using namespace, but i just put it there cause i think it will be more understandable.

Comment: @mattphillips I've used the `string(path.ToAscii())`, but it's still the same.

Answer (score 0):

I notice that you have:

```
deskew(filename); //filename string
```

but you have

```
void DImage::deskew(string filename, unsigned int angle)
```

So what happened to the 'angle' parameter?

Comment: sorry sir, but in my first code, i intentionally not include the class so that it will not confuse the readers.
but in my program, i've wrote it like this, `Document->deskew(fname, wxAtoi(text));` Document is from DImage class.

Comment: You may not be confusing your readers ( who can say? ) but you are certainly misleading them.  Please post your real code, otherwise we cannot help you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can load an image from wxString with

```
Mat src_img = imread(mywxstring.mb_str().data());
```

If it doesn't work, check that the image exists and that imread need \\ or / in the paths.